# Dual-monitor VPC/VMware

Tags: multiple-monitors, virtualization, vmware-workstation, microsoft-virtual-pc

If there was a feature request for Virtual PC or VMWare, it would be dual-monitor support. Why hasn't this been done?

Comment: What specific versions are you looking at?

Comment: VMWare Fusion / Virtual PC 2007 / Windows Virtual PC (Windows 7)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It has, the VMWare workstation allows you to expand the veiw across two monitors.

The little tab at the top of the screen has a button to expand across both monitors.

See page 159 http://www.vmware.com/pdf/ws65_manual.pdf

Comment: I believe this was added in version 6.0

Comment: What about VMWare Player?

Answer (score 4):

Virtualbox appears to have this feature: http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=3166