# Multiple monitors with virtual machine

Tags: multiple-monitors, virtualbox, virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc

Is it possible to use multiple monitors with Windows Virtual PC 2007?

If not, are there any other virtual machines that do support multiple monitors?

Comment: Not sure about Virtual PC, but you can in VMWare: http://superuser.com/questions/15156/dual-monitor-vpc-vmware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WMware workstation does allow you to setup multiple monitors.

If you RDP into a windows guest OS running in any virtualization, I think you can use multiple monitors if you're using the Windows 7 RDP client, there is a checkbox that lets you select (use all my monitors for the remote session)

Answer (score 1):

With the release of VirtualBox 3.2, multi-monitor support for guests is now as easy as dragging a slider in the Settings page :) No need for headless/RDP stuff now. You can have 8 virtual monitors across 2 physical screens, if you really want to confuse yourself...

Answer (score 0):

VMware Fusion for the Mac supports dual monitors seamlessly between host and and guest operating systems.  I would presume that VMware Workstation on the PC has similar features, but of course it is not free.

In the free-for-personal-use realm, VirtualBox supports up to 64 virtual monitors, but only with XP (and probably Server 2003) guests at the moment:
http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#advanced-multimonitor

Basically, what you do with VirtualBox is set the VM up to run headless and then connect via VirtualBox's built-in RDP server to each of the virtual displays (even if the VM is running on localhost).  Of course, if you wanted to connect to several monitors all at once, you could create an .rdp file for each display and launch them all at once with a batch file or script.