# How to use multiple desktops within a Hyper-V hosted VM

Tags: multiple-monitors, virtual-machine, vpn

So, for work, I am using a system hosted within Hyper-V Server 2012 R2. I use this VM for work purposes only. The issue I am having is not being able to use more than one monitor while connected to corporate VPN. The Cisco AnyConnect software scans for and will not run if RDP session is active. I can still however use the VM in a single monitor via Hyper-V Manager. I have tried changing port number for RDP with no luck. I also tried installing RemoteFX, only to find out my GPU does not support DirectX11, I can purchase a DX11 card for cheap if it will quickly resolve my issue. The other option I have seen is API hooks to tell AnyConnect that it is not running RDP. I do nto feel skilled enough to be able to do this independently. Anyone have suggestions of what I might do to get multiple monitors functioning?

Comment: Its very likely you will have to move to something other then Hyper-V to meet your goals.  Purchasing a new graphic card that supports DX 11 will not resolve your problems.  http://superuser.com/questions/132857/multiple-monitors-with-virtual-machine?rq=1

Comment: I don't believe the Hyper-V client supports multiple monitors.  I think you may be out of luck on that point.

Comment: Well, then does anybody know of a way to mask the status of an RDP session, other than using API hooks? Or is there a simple solution for api hooks?

Comment: Answer: This can be done with a guest running Windows 8.1 or server 2012 r2. I am doing it successfully now. Documentation in this article: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282274.aspx